# Grails 3 application in intellij

Tags: grails

I downloaded grails 3. I have old book about grails 1. I have same problems.

```
grails> create-app qotd
| Error Command not found create-app
Did you mean: create-script or create-taglib or create-unit-test?
```

why does not work?

[image: project]

I want to create a decorator

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>QOTD &raquo; <g:layoutTitle/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="
    <g:resource dir='css' file='snazzy.css' />
    " />
    <g:layoutHead />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <img src="
    <g:resource dir='images' file='logo.png'/>
    " alt="logo"/>
</div>
<g:layoutBody />
</body>
</html>
```

it is impossible to find the folders css and image. What their path?

Answer (score 0):

In Grails 3.x the plugin

```
  compile 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.8.2'
```

is used by default (check your `build.gradle` file)

Your decorator would look like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>QOTD &raquo; <g:layoutTitle/></title>
    <asset:stylesheet href="snazzy.css" />
    <g:layoutHead />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <asset:img src="logo.png" alt="logo"/>
</div>
<g:layoutBody />
</body>
</html>
```

and all your static files should be under `grails-app/assets`.